# PHP Выполнить функцию по нахождению шаблонного текста

Tags: php

Прошу подсказать,
как можно средствами php заменить часть текста на выполнение функции. К примеру, идет текст:

```
"И вот вышел из дома {{{1,5}}} и ушел."
```

Как сделать, чтобы вместо `{{{1,5}}}` выводился ответ от `function(a,b)` - где в данном случае `a` = 1 и `b` = 5.

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: В шаблонизаторе twig, насколько я знаю, такой функционал имеется..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать `preg_replace_callback`. Довольно простенький пример:

```
<?php

function replaceCallback($matches)
{
   return sum($matches[1], $matches[2]);
}

function sum($a, $b) {
   return $a + $b;
}

$text = 'Test text number {{{1,0}}}. It`s about number {{{1,1}}}. Good luck';

echo preg_replace_callback(
   "{{{{(\d),(\d)}}}}",
   "replaceCallback",
   $text
);
```

Результатом выполнения будет строка:
`Test text number 1. It's about number 2. Good luck`
Далее функцию можно развивать как угодно, если возможны различные варианты применяемых функций в зависимости от паттерна - можно использовать `preg_replace_callback_array`

Comment: Если используется 7.4 то можно сделать распечатку массива сразу и можно обойтись без промежуточной функции.
```preg_replace_callback('{{{{(\d),(\d)}}}}', 'sum', ...$arg)```